# MYSQL selection - particular case

Tags: mysql, select, multi-table

I have a first table T1 with 2 columns:

> 'id','info'

Examples of value:

> 'p1','infoP1'
>   'p2','infoP2'
>   'c1','infoC1'
>   'c2','infoC2'
>   'c3','infoC3'
>   'e4','infoE4'

I have a second table T2 with 2 column:

> 'id_p','id_c'

Examples of value:

> 'p1','c1'
>   'p1','c2'
>   'p2','c3'
>   'p2','c4'

I can't change the structure of these tables.
I want to make a SELECT to get the following result:

> 'idE','infoE','infoP'

with the following value:

> 'c1','infoC1','infoP1'
>   'c2','infoC2','infoP1'
>   'c3','infoC3','infoP2'
>   'c4','infoC4','infoP2'

But I haven't succeeded.
How can I achieve this?

EDIT: finally I did a mix of sub requests and I succeed to get the good result.
Thank you all for helping me !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where are your attempt(s)? So we can help you by explaining why something is wrong and why.

Comment: You columns you want to select `'idE','infoE','infoP'` what columns do they map to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join T2 table two times with T1 table. First time to get "info" for "id_c" and second time to get "info" for "id_p".

This should work:

```
SELECT j.id_c, f.info, s.info 
FROM T1 as f, T2 as j, T1 as s 
WHERE f.id=j.id_c AND s.id=j.id_p;
```

Comment: Thank you for you proposition. It's very interresting.
I get the good count of row, but the data of the second column is the same of the third column. So it's not exactly what I want

Comment: Have you certain about that? Because I tried this and works fine here... See image bellow: http://imgur.com/a/4ByIQ

Comment: Maybe you need to change the alias for output columns. Look: [SELECT j.id_c, f.info as info_c, s.info as info_p ...]

Comment: That really help me, but I can't upvote your answer, I don't have enough reputation :/ Indeed, I think I made something wrong : my request is more complex than the example I did, so I had to do something wrong.

Comment: I test it with a simple example and that works, so the problem is on my side, your proposition is perfect !

Answer (score 1):

if you want to select data from two tables by using same id. The following query may help you:

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 AS T1 JOIN TABLE2 AS T2 WHERE T1.id = T2.id

Comment: Thank you, but my question was not about join table, but succeed to get in the result 2 columns on the same table, with different value.